# Put value into char 2D array

Tags: c, arrays

I try to put value of two integers into char array.
If I have:

```
x = 3;
y = 5;
```

then I want to have

```
links[0][0] = "3,5";
```

I have this code now, but I don't know how can I continue.

```
char** links = (char**) calloc(SRTM_SIZE, sizeof(char*));
if(links)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < SRTM_SIZE; i++)
    {
        links[i] = (char*)calloc(SRTM_SIZE, sizeof(char));
        //memset(links[i], 0, sizeof(*links[i] * SRTM_SIZE));
    }
}

x = strtok(temp, ",");
y = strtok(NULL, ",");

int xx = atoi(x);
int yy = atoi(y);

//Some calculation with x and y and if it's okay, then I need to put value of x and y to array, but I don't know how

printf("%s\n", links[0][0]);
```

edited:

What exactly I need is matrix (propably 1201x1201) of strings. Into cells (not into all, but propably into most of them) I need put string values. This values can be from "0,0" to "1200, 1200". And later in program I need to acces to all cells with strings values, because each value is position of one of adjacent cells.

Comment: How do you plan on using a char's space to store a string of size more than one byte?

Answer (score 1):

`links[0][0]` is of single byte. You can store only `1` byte to it ,i.e, a single character. These two characters would store into the two different memory location, say, `link[0][0]` and `link[0][1]`. Then you also need a `\0` character to use `%s` to print them.
The statement

```
printf("%s\n", links[0][0]);
```

is wrong `%s` is used for strings but `links[0][0]` is a `char`.
You can do this as

```
sprintf(links[0], "%d,%d", xx,yy);
printf("%s\n", links[0]);
```

Test code after changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SRTM_SIZE 5

int main(void){
    char** links = (char**) calloc(SRTM_SIZE, sizeof(char*));
    if(links)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < SRTM_SIZE; i++)
        {
            links[i] = (char*)calloc(SRTM_SIZE, sizeof(char));
            //memset(links[i], 0, sizeof(*links[i] * SRTM_SIZE));
        }
    }

    char temp[5]="2,3";
    char *x = strtok(temp, ","); //strtok() returns pointer to char.
    char *y = strtok(NULL, ",");

    int xx = atoi(x);
    int yy = atoi(y);
    sprintf(links[0], "%d,%d", xx,yy);
    //Some calculation with x and y and if it's okay, then I need to put value of x and y to array, but I don't know how

    printf("%s\n", links[0]);

}
```

Comment: So I need to change type od my array?

Comment: I don't try it yet. But if I use your code, will I have in each cell one string?
PS I edited my question.

Comment: What do you mean by *each cell one string* ?

Comment: Each cell (links[r][c]) contains char[] value from "0,0" to "1200,1200". I need save in each cell position of another cell.

Comment: `links[r][c` can contains only one character. It is `links[r]` which contains `"0,0"` or `"1200,1200"` string.

Comment: Any way how I can save more than one character to links[r][c]?

Comment: You can't. At least in C.

Comment: And if I'll create only one dimensional array m *char array = malloc(1201 * 1201 * char[sizeof("1200,1200"), will this work? Or can you give me a advice how I can solve my problem?

Comment: Isn't my answer answer your question? Could you be more specific what actually you are trying to do? You may provide some examples.

Answer (score 1):

use sprintf

```
sprintf(links[0][0],"%d,%d",x,y);
```

**but before change links[0][0] to string(char*)**

**`"3,5" is string not a character.`**

more info http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/

Comment: Don't you think `link[0][0]` should be `link[0]`?

Comment: Might have you forget to see **>'but before change links[0][0] to string(char*)'**

Comment: What is this `string(char*)` type?

Comment: In C, String is represented/referred by **`char*`**. In this case, `link[0]` is of `char*` type but according to requirement of 'asker', link[0][0] must contains string. He needs to change its type by one level.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a value to a 2D array the way you do it. This is how it works:

```
arr[0][0]= x;
```

`arr[0][0]` refers to a single location, that is row 0, and column 0.

If you have `arr[2][2]`, you will have to specify where you want to put your value in the 2D array. If you want it in the first row, at the last column:

```
arr[0][2]= x;
```

You may visualize a 2D array as follows:

```
int  arr[3][2]:

             column 0     column 1

row 0       |arr[0][0]| |arr[0][1]|
row 1       |arr[1][0]| |arr[0][1]|
row 2       |arr[2][0]| |arr[0][1]|
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int len;
    int x = 3, y = 5;
    len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d,%d", x, y);
    char *link = malloc(len + 1);
    sprintf(link, "%d,%d", x, y);
    printf("%s\n", link);
    free(link);
    return 0;
}
```